# How to use my own format together with the plain format in Texpad

Tags: plain-tex, format-files, texpad, ide

I managed to create a format file using \dump, but how do I set TeXpad to recognize it?

I would like to use TeXpad. I always use the plain format, and TeXpad is heavy on LaTeX; it can run plain, but I also have my own format in addition to plain.

I have asked TeXifier, but they were unhelpful.

Comment: what's the name of your format?

Comment: I named it Pformat. It is just a set of macros to format various books I have written. I hope you can help. I have been using the old Textures from BlueSky, which is why I am stuck at Mac OS 10.14, so I would very much like to change to TeXpad. Thanks

Comment: my apologies, but I could not install this version of TeXifier (formerly TeXPad?), so I cannot reproduce the issue or provide any help... je suis désolée...